# How do I call a remote T-SQL procedure to restore a remote .bak database file to a remote SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, execution

I have backed up an SQL Server database to a file called `HACK_BACK.bak`. I have copied that `.bak` file to a remote server that hosts another SQL Server instance.

That remote server has a procedure called `RestoreDatabase` which has code to restore the `.bak` file to that remote SQL Server instance.

On my local SQL Server database, I have a linked server that connects to that server where I call that `RestoreDatabase` procedure.

When I call that remote procedure using the linked server, I get this error:

> Cannot open backup device 'G:\DROPZONE\HACK_MACK.bak'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).

This remote procedure is being called from my local SQL Server, but the context of execution appears to be local which is why I get the error. I want the procedure to use the remote server's `G:` drive and to restore that `.bak` file to that remote SQL Server instance.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, if you call the remote proc like this on your local, it should work

```
--linked server = REMOTE 
EXEC REMOTE.DB.RestoreDatabase 'G:\fileToRestore.bak'
```

That should run it on the REMOTE SQL instance with local G:, no?

I'm not sure what exact sequence you're running now

Another option is maybe use PowerShell (outside of SQL) to connect to REMOTE SQL instance to initiate the procedure to restore. Heck, look into dbatools.io even

Comment: Hi, yeah that's what I'm doing, but I think what MS SQL Server is doing, is  making the context my local server instead of the remote server which is why it cannot find the 'G:' drive folder, There is no 'G:' driver folder on my local server, but there is on the remote server.  Does that make more sense?

Your suggestion about using PowerShell is what I'm thinking about doing, but if there's a pure SQL solution to it, I'd prefer to use that.

Comment: I used powershell and that worked.  I updated the stored procedure on the remote SQL instance by putting in a master.sys.xp_cmdshell command to call the powershell script which contains the RESTORE command within the PowerShell's 'sqlps' Invoke-SqlCmd command.  All good in the hood.  :)

Comment: Good to hear PowerShell is indeed powerful :) 
I'm surprised a remote-call-execution would use local context instead..